# iconfont：How to make iconfont work in flutter

Tags: flutter, fonts

## i use iconfont in flutter，but it can not work properly，

it  looks like a  'X'  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUwsP.png)

I define it in pubsepc.yaml：

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    - family: iconfont
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/iconfont.ttf
```

and this is how i use it:

```
MaterialApp(
     home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(title: Text('data'),),
       body: Center(
         child: Container(child: Icon(IconData(0xe60d,fontFamily: 'iconfont'),color: Colors.amber,size: 50.0,),)
       ),
     ),
   ),
```

the "0xe60d" has been defined in the iconfont.ttf ,  i try to replace it to  another defined icon , but it is  also useless

who  can help me? Sincere thanks

Comment: however，i uninstall，install the app and restart VS Code several times ，then i can work right now，but i still dont know why...

Comment: Have to tried "flutter clean" command and then run the project.
Because as you mentioned that after uninstalling the app it worked. So maybe cleaning the build and rebuilding it may work.

Comment: thanks for your advise，i'll  try to clean the project if it happen again

Answer (score 0):

Generate your icon font with this tool: http://fluttericon.com/